# Use singleton with Dependency Injection (Castle Windsor)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, singleton, castle-windsor

I have created a project to understand windsor castle and singleton. To achieve this I have the following code

Controller:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private readonly IOfflineUserService _offlineUser; 
    public AdminController()
    {
        _offlineUser = OfflineUserService.instance;
    }
    [OutputCache(Duration = 20, VaryByParam = "none", Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server, NoStore = true, SqlDependency = "Default:Admin")]
    public ActionResult test()
    {
        var data = _offlineUser.GetAllOfflineUsers();
        return View(data);
    }
}
```

Singleton Base Class:

```
    public abstract class SingletonBase<T> where T : class
    {
    #region Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Static instance. Needs to use lambda expression
    /// to construct an instance (since constructor is private).
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly Lazy<T> sInstance = new Lazy<T>(() => CreateInstanceOfT());

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the instance of this singleton.
    /// </summary>
    public static T Instance { get { return sInstance.Value; } }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an instance of T via reflection since T's constructor is expected to be private.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static T CreateInstanceOfT()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), true) as T;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Service Class:

```
  public class OfflineUserService : SingletonBase<OfflineUserService>,IOfflineUserService
{

    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
           private readonly IAdminRepository _adminRepository;

    public OfflineUserService()
    {

    }

    public OfflineUserService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
        IUserRepository userRepository,
        IAdminRepository adminRepository,
        )
    {
        _adminRepository = adminRepository;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _userRepository = userRepository;

    }
     public List<OfflineUsers> GetAllOfflineUsers()
    {
    //Some Code
    }
}
```

So in the controller instead of passing OfflineUserService.instance; I want to pass IOfflineUserService.instance so that I can use it. I don't know how to achieve this. Dependency injection is working fine if I pass it through constructor

```
   public AdminController(IOfflineUserService offlineUser)
    {
        _offlineUser = offlineUser;
    }
```

but as I want to use singleton so to achieve this I can create the instance as mention in the code but I don't know how to create the singleton instance of an interface. Please suggest if I am doing anything wrong as I am trying to understand the behavior so that I can start using it in Projects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, but It seems you are doing something very wrong...

When you hire an IoC container in your project you have let him doing its job: creating instance, any instance have to create/released through the container([RRR pattern](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Three-Calls-Pattern&NS=Windsor)). No exception(of course data/model classes are excluded since are not even registered in the container).

In your case, you don't need the SingletonBase: the container will do the job for you. You simply have to register your component *OfflineUserService* and tell to the container that has to be managed as a Singleton

```
container.Register(
Component
.For<IOfflineUserService>()
.ImplementedBy<OfflineUserService>()
.LifestyleSingleton())
```

Beware you are making a [very bad hierarchy error](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/) in your sample:

Your service(OfflineUserService) depends on an other component which is a UnitOfWork, that usually should have a PerWebRequest lifestyle(in a web app). If OfflineUserService will be threated a Singleton, UnitOfWork instance ends up to be a "singleton" as well... that's gonna be your worst nightmare as soon as you put your code in prod :)

Comment: Thanx a lot!!!! but I have registered   UnitOfWork as Component.For<IUnitOfWork>()
                            .ImplementedBy<UnitOfWork>()
                            .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest, so still it will be treated as singleton?????

Comment: Yes it will... the instance which is the dependecy of a singleton instance(OfflineUserService) will. Read VERY carefully the ploeh post about captive dependency... as workaround you should have a factory(TypedFactory see windsor wiki) as dependecy of your singleton(OfflineUserService): the factory will create the instance according to the component registration

Answer (score 0):

Try if you can create your interface with property to get instance like this :

```
public interface IOfflineUserService<T> where T : class
{
    T GetServiceInstance { get; }
}
```

And while implementing in your class return the instance through this property :

```
public class OfflineUserService : SingletonBase<OfflineUserService>,IOfflineUserService<OfflineUserService>
{
    public OfflineUserService GetServiceInstance
    {
        get {
                return Instance;
            }  
    }
}
```

Then you can access it in controller with dependency injection.